# NestJs TypeORM configuration using AWS secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, nestjs, typeorm, aws-secrets-manager

please does anyone have an example/ tutorial on how / better way to get TypeORM configs from AWS secret manager (DB_PASSWORD, DB_PORT, ...)

I found examples for SSM but not for AWS secret manager.

Thank you.

Comment: Has anyone got an approach on this ..? using AWS secret manager with nestjs typeorm